# Multiple async request do not store anything to cache

Tags: android, caching, retrofit, okhttp

How can i save to cache file when do multiple async requests at similar time. Right now the cache file for this specific request is empty at the end (for other requests everything is working fine).

Im using standard OKHttp caching mechanism along with retrofit

Is there a way to block cache files until get closed and saved?